# Insert images of a folder into an array using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if it's possible to get a sequence of pictures into an array. I'd like to use JavaScript if possible, if not can it be possible with PHP and how?

So I created a map called "images/cars", which contains a lot of images. All the pictures have a different name. One is called: "audi", another one is called: "mercedes" and so on. They all are the same type (`.gif`).

I can do this manually like:

```
var pictures = ["audi.gif", "mercedes.gif", "aston martin.gif", ....]
// and so on
```

But that is too much work. Also, when I upload a new picture to the "images" folder, I have to manually add the new image to the array.

Here is my full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var cars= ["audi.gif", "mercedes.gif", "aston martin.gif", "bmw.gif", "ferrari.gif"];
      var outputRandomImage = "";   

      function myFunction() {   
        for (var i = cars.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
          var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
          var randomImage = cars[random];   
    
          cars[random] = cars[i]; 
          cars[i] = randomImage;
          outputRandomImage += '<img src="images/cars/' + randomImage + '">' + "<br>";
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputRandomImage;
        }   
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope someone here could help. I'm open to any ideas, recommendations, and suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Clearly you cannot get files on the server with Javascript, because it is ran in the browser after the server has served the html. However, you can use `scandir()` in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and then use that to generate Javascript with an array in it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create another PHP page

```
$folder = "."; // folder with the image files
$scan = scandir($folder);
$files = [];

foreach($scan as $file_name)
{
    if (!is_dir("$folder/$file_name"))
    {
        $array_push($files, $file_name) //  if it is not a directory add it to the files list
    }
}
$json_string = json_encode($ar);
echo $json_string;
```

And for the javascript

```
$.post("getCars.php", function(data, status){
    if(status==="success"){
        cars = JSON.parse(data)
    }
});
```